# How do I create Upgrade actions in the Feature.xml file using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, feature-upgrade

We have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 for a SharePoint 2010 application that is currently in Production (version 1.0.0.0).

I am making some changes to the solution to be deployed as version 1.1.0.0. I need to be able to deploy the new solution as an upgrade, and see I can create upgrade actions in the Feature.xml files for the various features that are included in the package (see [MSDN: Upgrading Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544511.aspx)).

However, there is no Feature.xml file in the VS solution, and am wondering how I go about creating the upgrade actions. Do I need to edit the Feature.xml files outside of visual studio or are there some "hidden" away within visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

I think VS.NET does not support the upgrade using FEATURE Designer. But you are not helpless.. you can edit the FEATURE manifest manually and VS.NET will merge the edits with designer elements. Open the Designer and then click on manifest and then edit in the bottom, as shown below.

[image]

Also check out: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html